# Should I know who Tsutsukawa Azusa is as of the end of Durarara!! ×2 Ten?

Tags: durarara

When Anri dials Mika at the end of the last episode of *Durarara!! ×2 Ten* (episode 24 of ×2), we see a shot of some of the contacts on her phone.

[image: Anri's phone contacts]

Entry #6, highlighted in the screenshot above, is someone named Tsutsukawa Azusa (筒川アズサ). As of this point in the story, am I supposed to know who that is? It's awfully difficult to keep track, what with DRRR having so many characters.

(Incidentally, the rest of that list is, in order: Akabayashi; Kadota; Karisawa; Shinra; Kida; Aoba; (Tsutsukawa); Togusa; Harima. Curiously, she only has 12 contacts in her phone.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

She is one of Karisawa's cosplayer friends, the girl that made Anri cosplay in one of the episodes.

[image: Azurin and Reh-chan at the hospital]

A screenshot of Azurin and Reh-chan.

> Azurin and Reh-chan were amongst Karisawa’s fellow cosplayers, and were about the same age as Anri.

A quote from [Volume 10 Chapter 2](http://popsiclete.blogspot.sg/2013/10/drrr-vol10-chapter-2-part-12.html).

Comment: Ah, I remember her now. That was episode 10 of _Ten_ when she's with Karisawa and they invite Anri to cosplay with them.

Comment: She is not a important character so it is actually fine for you to forget her.